# grep command to extract all sequences of length 2 in order

Tags: bash, macos, grep

I would like to extract machine code from the otool command output.

otool -t someFile outputs e.g.

```
0000000000000000    48 31 ff 40 b7 02 48 31 f6 40 b6 01 48 31 d2 48 
.
.
0000000000000070    c8 28 b0 3b 52 68 2f 2f 62 69 0f 05
```

How can grep be used to extract each hex value, or sequence of 2 characters and add them to a string, to then be able to add `\x` before each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xargs` with `grep` regex:

```
otool -t file | grep -ioE "(?:\t)([A-Z0-9]{2}\s)+" | xargs printf "\\\x%s"
```

Output should look something like this:

```
\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x83\xec\x10\x48\x8d\x05 ...
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a lot. Why the three \ instead of 2?

Comment: @jarryd: You’re welcome! The backslash ( \ ) needs to be escaped once for itself  ( \\ ) so that ( \x ) will act as a literal, so you end up with ( \\\x ).

Comment: It's a bug - unless you have something very specific youre trying to accomplish, to avoid shell interpretation printf formatting strings should always be enclosed in single quotes, not double: `printf '\\x%s'`. The other bug, I think, is that AFAIK `(?:\t)` is a perl-ism and so not supported by grep without the `-P` option (and of course -P should be avoided since it's highly experimental so YMMV with that)

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the clarification, so I presume `\t` could be used by itself in this circumstance?  Another thing I noticed was that after the printf there’s no line feed after the output. It’s easy to put an echo after it, although there’s probably a better way that you might know of...

Comment: I never use perl-isms so I'm not actually sure what that expression means but if you're just trying to get past a tab then you could pipe through `cut -f2-`. The only way I can think off to get the necessary newline at the end of the output would be an echo at the end. Let me see if I can think of an alternative and if so I'll post an answer. May not be any better, idk...

Comment: OK, I posted an alternative.

Comment: @EdMorton: `(?:.)` means "match but don't capture". I tried `(\t)` as opposed to `(?:\t)` and it had the same effect, so grep must know just to ignore the `?:` and treat it as a capture group. Regarding the the lack of linefeed at the end, I simply just added `; echo` and it worked fine, although I would think there's a nice way to include it with `xargs` perhaps.

Comment: When I run that grep command (GNU grep 3.0) on the input file in my question It doesn't output anything so idk what it's matching on for you. Are you using the same format of input as I am with a long number then a tab then 2-digit numbers?

Comment: @EdMorton: I'm using `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` and I believe that's what the OP has to since he's using Mac, so there must be some inherent differences.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and alternatives. Yes I am using macos. I was modifying an objdump command to extract x64 machine code from a file but it wasn't working as expected so needed an alternative approach. This has already saved me a lot of time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If your first field of odtool output is separated by a tab from the rest then this might be what you're looking for:

```
otool -t someFile | awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/^| /,"\\x",$2); print $2}'
```

e.g.

```
$ cat file
0000000000000000        48 31 ff 40 b7 02 48 31 f6 40 b6 01 48 31 d2 48
0000000000000070        c8 28 b0 3b 52 68 2f 2f 62 69 0f 05

$ awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/^| /,"\\x",$2); print $2}' file
\x48\x31\xff\x40\xb7\x02\x48\x31\xf6\x40\xb6\x01\x48\x31\xd2\x48
\xc8\x28\xb0\x3b\x52\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x0f\x05
```

Given the comment below from l'L'l that implies there's blank lines and blank chars at the end of lines to be ignored, this may be what you actually want:

```
otool -t someFile | awk -F'\t' 'NF>1{sub(/ +$/,""); gsub(/^| /,"\\x",$2); print $2}'
```

Comment: When piped from otool [this was the output](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/ccb9f306e1cd8612451b43a700499e0e).

Comment: So otool outputs some blank lines that should be discarded and puts a blank char at the end of the line that should be ignored? Could you please post the output of otool somewhere and what the expected output is of the command that processes it?

Comment: Yes, here's a [sample](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/ccb9f306e1cd8612451b43a700499e0e) of the output — hope that helps :).